# Why doesn grunt-contrib-imagemin reduce PNGs by 80% but JPG by only <0.1%?

Tags: javascript, node.js, image, gruntjs, compression

So, I'm relatively new to Grunt.

I've been playing around with grunt-contrib-imagemin.

I have noticed that when compressing PNGs, it does a great job. It averagely compresses buy 80%.

But the jpeg compression is almost pointless. It often compresses just a couple of KB from a 3mb picture.

How do I make it better a compressing jpegs?

Gruntfile.js

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: 'src/*.js',
        dest: 'build/main.min.js'
      }
    },
      imagemin: {
        png: {
          options: {
            optimizationLevel: 7
          },
          files: [
            {
              expand: true,
              cwd: 'src/img/png/', // cwd is 'current working directory'
              src: ['**/*.png'],
              dest: 'build/img/png', // Could also match cwd.
              ext: '.png'
            }
          ]
        },
        jpg: {
          options: {
            progressive: true
          },
          files: [
            {
              expand: true, // Tell Grunt where to find our images and where to export them to.
              cwd: 'src/img/', // cwd is 'current working directory'
              src: ['**/*.jpg'],
              dest: 'build/img', // Could also match cwd.
              ext: '.jpg'
            }
          ]
        }
      }
  });

  // Load the plugins
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
  // Default tasks
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify', 'imagemin']);



};
```

CLI

```
C:\Users\bmildren\Desktop\Sites\grunt-test>grunt
Running "uglify:build" (uglify) task
>> 1 file created.

Running "imagemin:png" (imagemin) task
? src/img/png/e4454c8df9.png (saved 1.37 MB)
Minified 1 image (saved 1.37 MB)

Running "imagemin:jpg" (imagemin) task
? src/img/5f468e98.jpg (saved 3.24 kB)
? src/img/photo-1414604582943-2fd913b3cb17.jpg (saved 3.24 kB)
? src/img/photo-1416424500327-a57ace7358b8.jpg (saved 3.24 kB)
? src/img/photo-1416838375725-e834a83f62b7.jpg (saved 3.24 kB)
? src/img/photo-1419332563740-42322047ff09.jpg (saved 3.24 kB)
Minified 5 images (saved 16.20 kB)

Done, without errors.

C:\Users\bmildren\Desktop\Sites\grunt-test>
```

Comment: I'd imagine this all depends on how much compression the files have been saved with.

Comment: @Andy But if you run the images through https://tinyjpg.com/ they will drop about 60-80% of the file weight

Answer (score 2):

grunt-contrib-imagemin uses `jpegtran` to optimize jpg files.

It uses the options `-copy none -optimize` which strips meta-data from the file and optimizes the [Huffman table](http://www.impulseadventure.com/photo/optimized-jpeg.html) which is a lossless process.

`jpegtran` does not perform lossy operations such as changing the image quality. So to answer your question, you can not use grunt-contrib-imagemin to optimize jpg files further, you would need to use something else.

png files are optimized with `optipng` which is able to apply different algorithms which appear to be more effective for that file type while remaining lossless.